# Require drop point to drag and drop 2 elements, then trigger event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a container accept 2 different draggable elements. I want the container to require both elements to be added and accepted and then trigger an event after

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
     var dfd2 = $.Deferred();

     $('#draggable').draggable({
         start: function () {
             $(this).parent().animate({
                 opacity: '0.5'
             }, 1000);
         },
         stop: function () {
             $(this).parent().animate({
                 opacity: '1'
             }, 1000).end().remove();
         }
     });

     $('#droppable').droppable({
         accept: ("#draggable", "#draggable2"),
         drop: function (event, ui) {
             $(this).html('Dropped');
             dfd1.resolve();
             dfd2.resolve();
         }
     });

     // this will trigger when both dfds have been resolved
     $.when(dfd1.promise(), dfd2.promise()).then(function () {
         alert("done!")
     });
 });
```

Comment: so what's your question? one thing I noticed is that you're only accepting `#dragglable`, you should add `#draggable2`

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.  First, you are only calling `draggable` on `#draggable` and never on `#draggable2`.  Then your `accept` was not correct, it should be `accept: "#draggable, #draggable2"`.  Finally, you were resolving both defereds on any drop.  You need to only resolve the appropriate deferred.

http://jsfiddle.net/H9CQt/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
     var dfd2 = $.Deferred();

     $('#draggable, #draggable2').draggable({
         start: function () {
             $(this).parent().animate({
                 opacity: '0.5'
             }, 1000);
         },
         stop: function () {
             $(this).parent().animate({
                 opacity: '1'
             }, 1000).end().remove();
         }
     });

     $('#droppable').droppable({
         accept: "#draggable, #draggable2",
         drop: function (event, ui) {
             $(this).html('Dropped');

             if(ui.draggable.is("#draggable")){
                 dfd1.resolve();
             } else {
                 dfd2.resolve();
             }
         }
     });

     // this will trigger when both dfds have been resolved
     $.when(dfd1.promise(), dfd2.promise()).then(function () {
         alert("done!")
     });
 });
```